# How to assign a value to an enum member at runtime?

Tags: c

Let I have below program. I would like to assign the value to the enum member at run time. How can i do it?

```cpp
typedef enum test{
    a, b
}test;
typedef struct abc{
    test Test;
}abc;
int main(){

    abc ab;
    ab.Test.a = 5;//Throwing an error as "Expression must have class type"
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: If you're getting "Expression must have class type", you're not doing C. (C has no classes.)

Comment: Uh, do you know what an [enum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) is? (Hint, constants)

Comment: I get `error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union`. Is that more helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `enum` is just a way to give names to some `constants`, for clarity reasons.

It can be useful because, contrary to `defines`, the names you set for your variables are (typically) not discarded by your compiler, hence you can see them while going through your program with a debugger.

If you want to regroup variables and set values to them, use `structures` instead.

Answer (score 3):

firstly enum values are constants and hence, they cannot be changed in code, later on.

Secondly, I don't know what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this, instead?

```
typedef struct test{
    int a, b;
} test;
typedef struct abc{
    test Test;
} abc;

int main(){

    abc ab;
    ab.Test.a = 5;
    return 0;
}
```